# I am trying to deploy my nextjs app to git hub page. but it is not deploying in the correct way

Tags: reactjs, github, next.js, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my nextjs app to git hub page. but the production is very slow. and everytime it publishes shows only the read.md. the way I deployed is below.

1. installed the gh-pages into devDependencies.
2. added replacer.js with following code..

   ```
   const replace = require("replace-in-file");
       const options = {
         //you may need to modify the file address to suite your project
         files: "./build/index.html",
         from: [/src="\//g, /href="\//g],
         to: ['src="./', 'href="./'],
       };
       (async function () {
         try {
           const results = await replace(options);
           console.log("Replacement results:", results);
         } catch (error) {
           console.error("Error occurred:", error);
         }
       })();
   ```
3. updated next.config.js is below

```
module.exports = {
      Images: {
        domains: ["/public", "fakestoreapi.com"],
        env: {
          PUBLIC_URL: "https://imangi.github.io/amazon-clone",
          assetPrefix: "./",
        },
      },
    };
```

4. updated package.json file is as below.

   ```
   {
     "name": "amazon-clone",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "homepage": "https://imangi.github.io/amazon-clone",
     "description": "amazon clone with react & next.js",
     "main": "index.js",
     "scripts": {
       "replaceFilePaths": "node replacer.js",
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
       "dev": "next",
       "build": "next build && next export -o build && npm run replaceFilePaths",
       "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
       "predeploy": "npm run build",
       "export": "next export -o build && npm run replaceFilePaths",
       "start": "next start"
     },
     "author": "Imangi Nanayakkara",
     "license": "ISC",
     "dependencies": {
       "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
       "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
       "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.0",
       "firebase": "^9.8.2",
       "firebase-admin": "^10.2.0",
       "next": "^12.1.6",
       "next-sitemap": "^3.0.5",
       "react": "^18.1.0",
       "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
       "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
       "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23"
     },
     "devDependencies": {
       "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
       "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
       "postcss": "^8.4.14",
       "tailwindcss": "^3.1.2"
     }
   ```

   }
5. Executed the following command:

   npm run deploy
6. pushing _next folder with .nojekyll file to gh-pages branch.

Comment: Maybe this tutorial will help you:) https://gregrickaby.blog/article/nextjs-github-pages

Comment: That `next.config.js` doesn't look right. `Images` should be `images`, and should be at the root level of the object along with `env` and `assetPrefix`, i.e. `module.exports = { images: { domains: ["/public", "fakestoreapi.com"] }, env: { PUBLIC_URL: "https://imangi.github.io/amazon-clone" }, assetPrefix: "./" };`.